# How to scale and move a mesh to specific location and axis in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I am a beginner and i am trying to move other mesh ,so that i can use as a wall and another mesh as floor .
But, i am unable to move the other mesh(smaller in the attached screen) .
Both the mesh is moving when i am using x,y,z transform (right side in screenshot).

Please help me in moving the smaller mesh towards bigger one and erect it as a wall and also scale the mesh in any axis by selecting it.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: let me know if you face further problems or just upload the blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack exchange! It appears that you are in edit mode and want to move the shorter plane near to the larger one(as described). You can just select the plane and move it using G hotkey, but make sure you are not selecting anything else other than the plane. You can go into edit mode > deselect everything (Double tap A or Alt A) > hover over the plane you want to move > press L to select that plane > use the move tool to move in the choice of your direction. I would recommend you to see some videos of Blender Guru, CGGeek, CGCookie to get started with blender.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harshvarsdhan.

Comment: Welcome! Make amazing artworks now.